# Safari rendering content disappearing

Tags: css, drupal-7, safari

I'm only noticing this in safari 5, but on most page refreshes, the second and third floated divs in the middle page content don't render correctly. The image gets cut off, sometimes the google font text doesn't display, sometimes the button gets doubled. It's very inconsistent, but a few refreshes and the issue comes up at least once.

site is at [dev.axiomllc.com](http://dev.axiomllc.com). I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on. It even works in IE7.

What it should look like:

[image]

What it does look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

turned out to be an issue with the way safari renders font-face within floated content. Switched from floated to inline-block and problems were solved.